# Cannot run androidTest in certain module

Tags: android, gradle, junit, junit4, android-testing

I am having a problem running an androidTest. It cannot locate my tests. The weird thing is, that it's only the case for a certain module. Other modules which I put the test into and configure their build.gradle files eqully are working. Here are some informations. Any help is very appreciated!

The output is as follows:

```
Running tests

$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class my.package.MainActivityTest my.package.module.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests
Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{my.package.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}
Empty test suite.
```

The test is located under

`myModule/src/androidTest/java/my/package/MainActivityTest.java`

and looks as follows:

```
@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void thisTestIsntExecuted() {
        assertEquals(1, 2);
    }
}
```

The modules build.gradle file has the following settings:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        (...)
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
dependencies {
    (...)
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1"
}
```

Instrumentation runner on device:

```
instrumentation:my.package.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner (target=my.package.module)
```

//edit: I had a closer look at the output from the run command and the instrumentation runner on the device. I forgot to add `.module` on two places.

Comment: junit is only included in tests, not androidTests. (see `testImplementation` vs `androidTestImplementation`)

Comment: Can you try editing your run configuration for the test and checking the instrumentation and test runner?

Comment: @Zoe thanks for your answer! Do you mean that I am missing the line:

`androidTestImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"`

I added it but there wasn't a change.

Comment: @DavidRawson thanks for your comment. On the run configurations page aren't really options for that. I think they were stipped with AS3. InstrumentationRunner is set via gradle.

Comment: So I found a way to run the test. I saw that when I click run in AS the triggered adb call is:

`adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class my.package.module.MainActivityTest my.package.module.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`

When manually call:
`adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class my.package.module.MainActivityTest my.package.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`

The test runs fine. So the instrumentation info has the wrong package when I click in AS on run. I have to get rid of the module part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out to solve the problem. As stated in the comment above I was able to start my tests manually with the command:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e class my.package.module.MainActivityTest my.package.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

The run configuration which Android Studio created for me executed the command:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e class my.package.module.MainActivityTest my.package.module.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

So as you can see a path was wrong, the `module` part was too much.

This path is the `testApplicationId` and can be changed via gradle, [see here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html). When it's not set, the value is automatically created by taking the `applicationId` and add a `.test` to it. This resulted in a wrong path in my case, maybe because I am generating the applicationId based on the build variant.

Don't forget to sync and clean.

Comment: Can this be ONLY run on MainActivity?

Comment: no thats just an example. the trick was in the different package-paths